# I can’t find England when in the NIV appointment system!

Tags: visas

I can’t find England in the appointment system! Please help! [image]

Comment: Can you find United Kingdom?

Answer (score 13):

The US Embassy in London and the US Consulate in Belfast do not use that form for visa applications, which is why neither "England" nor "United Kingdom" appear in the list. Instead, nonimmigrant visa applicants from the UK are directed to use [this form](https://ais.usvisa-info.com/en-gb/niv) to book appointments after completing a [DS-160](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/). More information on the process is available at [How to Apply](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/how-to-apply/).